# How to add image to localhost using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to store an image to my localhost. So far I have managed to allow users to get the image from their computer and preview the image. However, i am having trouble saving the image to the localhost after the users have previewed the image and click submit.

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()" data-max-size="41904" name="img"><br />
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<script>
   function previewFile(){
       var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
       var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
       var reader  = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function () {
           preview.src = reader.result;
       }

       if (file) {
           reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
       } else {
           preview.src = "";
       }
  }

  previewFile();  //calls the function named previewFile()
</script>

<input type='submit' value='Save Profile' />
```

Comment: How are you browsing to the page? http or file?

Comment: @AdrianLynch I am browsing the page using http

Comment: You need server-side code.

Comment: You cannot save image in your server (localhost or webhost) with client-code. You need upload image to server

Comment: Are your `<input>`s enclosed in a `<form>`?  If so, what is the `action` of that `form`?  When you press the `Save Profile` button, you need to tell it what to do, where to go, how to handle the request.

Comment: @AngeloDeMichaels Yes they are enclosed in a form. I have not stated an action for that form. I was confused about what the action is for downloading images to local directory.

Comment: @Kevin That's not strictly true; it is possible to save files locally with client side code only, for example with [this library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). But that should be reserved for rare circumstances where writing server-side code to save the file is infeasible.

Comment: Javasript is operationg in the clients browser. But you need a upload (HTTP-POST) to the server. You can do it with a form or just maniuplate it all via javascript. But it is a HTTP-Post anyways.